# Why the dynamic call results in “undefined function”?

Tags: macros, elixir, metaprogramming

I have a module that dynamically routes external calls to it’s own functions in the following way:

```rb
defmodule A do
  defmacro call(name) do
    quote do
      fun = & unquote(:"A.#{name}")(&1)
      fun.(:foo)
    end
  end

  def test(param), do: IO.inspect(param, label: "test")
end
#⇒ {:module, A, ..., {:test, 1}}
```

The module was successfully compiled and `A.test/1` is there.

```rb
A.test :foo
#⇒ test: :foo
```

Now I try to call it as:

```rb
defmodule B do
  require A
  def test, do: A.call(:test)
end
#⇒ ** (CompileError) iex:21: undefined function A.test/1
#      (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
#      (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:677: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
#      (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:249: IEx.Evaluator.handle_eval/5
```

What is wrong with this dynamic call dispatch and why the error message contradicts the reality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is misleading. `& unquote(:"A.#{name}")(&1)` will call a function literally named `A.test` in the current scope, not the `test/1` function of module `A`:

```
defmodule A do
  defmacro call(name) do
    quote do
      fun = & unquote(:"A.#{name}")(&1)
      fun.(:foo)
    end
  end

  def unquote(:"A.test")(param), do: IO.inspect(param, label: "!!!")
end

defmodule B do
  require A
  import A
  def test, do: A.call(:test)
end

B.test
```

Output:

```
!!!: :foo
```

To make it call the `test/1` function of module `A`, you can do `& A.unquote(:"#{name}")(&1)`:

```
defmodule A do
  defmacro call(name) do
    quote do
      fun = & A.unquote(:"#{name}")(&1)
      fun.(:foo)
    end
  end

  def test(param), do: IO.inspect(param, label: "test")
end

defmodule B do
  require A
  def test, do: A.call(:test)
end

B.test
```

Output:

```
test: :foo
```

Comment: I wonder now how the compiler knows that `A.unquote` should be treated completely different from, say, `A.foo`.